# How to run everything in a method in one class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, void

So Here's my question... I have a java program for checkers,  I want to initialize the checkers in a different class, as a method (I Think), and then create all of them.  Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/ansERKjv
So how do I call the method DoCreate() in my main class?
  Also if I want to do what I've stated above, but put `Create` in a different file, and then call the method `public void DoCreate()` how would I do that?  Would I have to import class Checker.  ThankS

```
import java.util.logging.*;
//Jake Sylvestre
public class Checkers 
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    //Creates all the checkers


}
}

class Checker
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int id;
    boolean white;
    boolean king;
}

class Create
{
        public void DoCreate()//Creates all the pieces and gives them starting values
        {

            //YES writing an algorithm to skip every other space would be more effecient for me, but would slow down code
            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            //WHITE BELOW
            Checker checker1 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker1.x=1;//starting x value
            checker1.y=1;//starting y value
            checker1.id=1;//Checker Id
            checker1.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end



            //intalizing checker 2
            //checker 2 create code starts
            Checker checker2 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker2.x=2;//starting x value
            checker2.y=1;//starting y value
            checker2.id=2;//Checker Id
            checker2.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker 2 create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker3 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker3.x=5;//starting x value
            checker3.y=1;//starting y value
            checker3.id=3;//Checker Id
            checker3.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker4 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker4.x=7;//starting x value
            checker4.y=1;//starting y value
            checker4.id=4;//Checker Id
            checker4.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end



            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker5 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker5.x=9;//starting x value
            checker5.y=1;//starting y value
            checker5.id=5;//Checker Id
            checker1.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end



            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker6 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker6.x=2;//starting x value
            checker6.y=2;//starting y value
            checker6.id=6;//Checker Id
            checker6.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker7 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker7.x=4;//starting x value
            checker7.y=2;//starting y value
            checker7.id=7;//Checker Id
            checker7.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker8 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker8.x=6;//starting x value
            checker8.y=2;//starting y value
            checker8.id=8;//Checker Id
            checker8.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker9 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker9.x=8;//starting x value
            checker9.y=2;//starting y value
            checker1.id=9;//Checker Id
            checker1.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker10 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker10.x=10;//starting x value
            checker10.y=2;//starting y value
            checker10.id=10;//Checker Id
            checker10.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker11 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker11.x=1;//starting x value
            checker1.y=3;//starting y value
            checker1.id=11;//Checker Id
            checker11.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker12 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker12.x=3;//starting x value
            checker12.y=3;//starting y value
            checker12.id=12;//Checker Id
            checker12.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker13 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker13.x=5;//starting x value
            checker13.y=3;//starting y value
            checker13.id=13;//Checker Id
            checker13.white=true;//Is it white?
            checker13.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker14 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker14.x=7;//starting x value
            checker14.y=3;//starting y value
            checker14.id=1;//Checker Id
            checker14.white=true;//Is it white?
            checker14.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker15 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker15.x=9;//starting x value
            checker15.y=3;//starting y value
            checker15.id=15;//Checker Id
            checker15.white=true;//Is it white?
            checker15.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end

            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker16 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker16.x=2;//starting x value
            checker16.y=4;//starting y value
            checker16.id=16;//Checker Id
            checker16.white=true;//Is it white?
            checker16.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end

            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker17 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker17.x=4;//starting x value
            checker17.y=4;//starting y value
            checker17.id=17;//Checker Id
            checker17.white=true;//Is it white?
            checker17.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end

            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker18 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker18.x=6;//starting x value
            checker18.y=4;//starting y value
            checker18.id=18;//Checker Id
            checker18.white=true;//Is it white?
            checker18.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end

            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker19 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker19.x=8;//starting x value
            checker19.y=4;//starting y value
            checker19.id=19;//Checker Id
            checker19.white=true;//Is it white?
            checker19.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end

            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker20 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker20.x=10;//starting x value
            checker20.y=4;//starting y value
            checker20.id=20;//Checker Id
            checker20.white=true;//Is it white?
            checker20.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker21 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker21.x=2;//starting x value
            checker21.y=10;//starting y value
            checker21.id=21;//Checker Id
            checker21.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker21.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker22 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker22.x=4;//starting x value
            checker22.y=10;//starting y value
            checker22.id=22;//Checker Id
            checker22.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker22.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker23 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker23.x=6;//starting x value
            checker23.y=10;//starting y value
            checker23.id=23;//Checker Id
            checker23.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker23.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker24 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker24.x=8;//starting x value
            checker24.y=10;//starting y value
            checker24.id=24;//Checker Id
            checker24.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker24.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker25 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker25.x=10;//starting x value
            checker25.y=10;//starting y value
            checker25.id=25;//Checker Id
            checker25.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker25.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker26 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker26.x=1;//starting x value
            checker26.y=9;//starting y value
            checker26.id=26;//Checker Id
            checker26.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker26.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end



            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker27 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker27.x=3;//starting x value
            checker27.y=9;//starting y value
            checker27.id=27;//Checker Id
            checker27.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker27.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker28 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker28.x=5;//starting x value
            checker28.y=9;//starting y value
            checker28.id=27;//Checker Id
            checker28.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker28.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker29 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker29.x=7;//starting x value
            checker29.y=9;//starting y value
            checker29.id=28;//Checker Id
            checker29.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker29.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end

            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker30 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker30.x=9;//starting x value
            checker30.y=9;//starting y value
            checker30.id=28;//Checker Id
            checker30.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker30.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker31 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker31.x=2;//starting x value
            checker31.y=8;//starting y value
            checker31.id=31;//Checker Id
            checker31.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker31.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end




            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker32 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker32.x=4;//starting x value
            checker32.y=8;//starting y value
            checker32.id=32;//Checker Id
            checker32.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker32.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker33 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker33.x=6;//starting x value
            checker33.y=8;//starting y value
            checker33.id=33;//Checker Id
            checker33.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker33.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker34 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker34.x=8;//starting x value
            checker34.y=8;//starting y value
            checker34.id=34;//Checker Id
            checker34.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker34.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker35 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker35.x=10;//starting x value
            checker35.y=8;//starting y value
            checker35.id=35;//Checker Id
            checker35.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker35.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker36 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker36.x=1;//starting x value
            checker36.y=7;//starting y value
            checker36.id=36;//Checker Id
            checker36.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker36.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker37 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker37.x=3;//starting x value
            checker37.y=7;//starting y value
            checker37.id=37;//Checker Id
            checker37.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker37.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker38 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker38.x=5;//starting x value
            checker38.y=7;//starting y value
            checker38.id=31;//Checker Id
            checker38.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker38.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end


            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker39 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker39.x=7;//starting x value
            checker39.y=7;//starting y value
            checker39.id=31;//Checker Id
            checker39.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker39.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end



            //intalizing checker 
            //checker  create code starts
            Checker checker40 = new Checker();//Creates the checker object
            checker40.x=9;//starting x value
            checker40.y=7;//starting y value
            checker40.id=40;//Checker Id
            checker40.white=false;//Is it white?
            checker40.king=false;//Is it a king
            //checker  create code end
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code *here* for all to see, not in a link that can go bad. You will want to strive to make it as easy as possible for others to understand your code, question, and problem, which will increase your chances of getting a decent quick answer. If your code is too large to post here, then it's probably too large to ask volunteers to review, and you'll have to put in some effort to shrink it a bit so we see the pertinent parts, enough to understand your problem, without drowning in unrelated code.

Comment: Next: you will want to learn about using arrays and for loops for your code can be shrunk quite a bit by using these.

Comment: Some reading on OOP might be a good idea

Comment: If you checkers need to be filled statically. I would suggest using a file to read out the checker data so you don't have to make such code.

Comment: So you wanted me to indent 376 lines of code?

Comment: Also I would use loops, but how do I define a loop as a certain to a certain checker,  so let's say I wanted a loop to set a variable of every checker to do somehting can i do say if' Checker /*(me referencing all checkers)*/<20 checker= white'

Comment: `"So you wanted me to indent 376 lines of code?"` -- please clarify as this doesn't make sense. If you post your code in the question editor, highlight it, and press the code button, the code gets indented for you. It will then be readable as code, if it is formatted well to begin with.

Comment: As for for loops, your code is extremely repetitive, and yes the logic of for loops will work if you work it out.

Comment: I'm sorry for the noob questions, but can you please explain to me how to check all checkers for a condition, here's my problem, I don't know how to increment the checkers (checker(12++;) is what i would do but thats not code, so can i just use id's to test code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change Checker to something like this:

```
class Checker {
   private int x;
   private int y;
   private int id;
   private boolean white;
   private boolean king = false; // to clarify the default value

   public Checker(int x, int y, int id, boolean white) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.id = id;
      this.white = white;
   }
   public boolean isKing() {
      return king;
   }
   public void setKing(boolean king) {
      this.king = king;
   }
   public int getX() {
      return x;
   }
   public int getY() {
      return y;
   }
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
   public boolean isWhite() {
      return white;
   }
}
```

Where you assign state to it in its constructor.

I'd create a CheckerSquare object that can hold a Checker object (or hold nothing).

I'd create a CheckersBoard class that is an 8 x 8 array of CheckerSquare objects.

I'd then use a for loop to fill the board's squares with appropriate Checker objects, and yes, if you work this out on paper, a for loop would work great for this, probably two of them though, one for white and one for black (though one could do it if you're a little clever).

I'd then create a Main class with a main method that initializes the objects above, and other necessary objects, such as a class to oversee the game itself, a class for Player, a class for the rules, and then get things started.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I run checker?

Comment: I could do this but how do i define say checker1 and that add it to checker 2, this is my problem

Comment: @JakeSylvestre: You don't need nor want it to say "checker1". Use an array or ArrayList and use `checkerArray[0]` or `checkerList.get(0)`. Again, you would be well served to learn to use these guys.

Comment: Thanks, I finally got that array thing on this cool video on [udemy](http://goo.gl/d8nGwX)